# Is there a "universal family of hypersurfaces"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, universal-property

Consider the category of (flat) families of degree $d$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$, i.e. objects are $X \to Y$ whose fibers are degree $d$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$, and morphisms are the pullback diagrams. Then, is there a terminal (universal) element in this category? i.e. any family can be uniquely pullbacked by this family.

I have considered the natural family on $|\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(d)|$, but the uniqueness does not hold. I tend to believe the universal family does not exists, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: This is a standard issue  in Geometric Invariant Theory. Such an object (the base) has to be the quotient of $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)| by automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^n$. The quotient does not exist in the category of schemes.

Comment: There is a universal family of smooth hypersurfaces with "level $N$ structure" whenever $N>2$; see https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.09291

Comment: If you want to remember the embedding as well, then this is a specific instance of the Hilbert scheme. Alternatively you can look at 28.3.5 of Vakil.

Comment: @Mohan I think this is exactly what I want. Could you give a reference about the statement that this quotient does not exist in the category of schemes?

Comment: May be you should look at Mumford-Fogarty, Geometric Invariant Theory.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thanks for the reference. I think this may be relative to what I want, but I cannot followed your paper (I am not familiar with stacks). Could you explain a little bit what is the "level structure"? I see you defined the functor $\mathcal C_{d,n}^{[N]}$, but it is quite abstract to me, and I cannot see how to relate my question.

Comment: @Akatsuki You might find the first two chapters of the book by Katz-Mazur on elliptic curves a good place to start. Sometimes, when a moduli functor is not representable by a scheme (or algebraic space), one considers a different (but closely related) moduli functor which turns out to be representable by a scheme. The precise definition of what a level structure is can be found in the paper, but roughly speaking, a level $\ell$ structure is "a trivialization of the $\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z}$-cohomology".